# Norm of Hilbert matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a Hilbert Matrix, ie $a_{ij}=(1+i+j)^{-1}$. Would you help me to prove that $\Vert A\Vert\leq \pi$ where the norm is standard euclidean norm.

Comment: Could you tell us with which norm you are working with? Thanks!

Comment: usual Euclidean norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For euclidean norm the norm of matrix $A$ may be defined as follows
$$
\Vert A\Vert=\sup\{\langle Ax,y\rangle:\quad x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n,\quad\Vert x\Vert_2\leq 1,\quad\Vert y\Vert_2\leq 1\}
$$
Hence (why?) it is enough to prove that for all positive reals $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$, $\{y_j\}_{j=1}^n$ holds
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\frac{x_i y_j}{i+j+1}\leq \pi\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^ny_j^2\right)^{1/2}
$$
This is so called [Hilbert's inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertsInequality.html). You can find its proof on page 155 of the book [The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class](http://estoyanov.net/files/MATAMATIKA/23982177-TheCauchy-Schwartz-Master-Class.pdf) by J. Michael Steele.