# Is the norm of the Hilbert matrix equal to $\pi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, hilbert-matrices

Let $A$ be a Hilbert matrix,

$$a_{ij}=\frac{1}{1+i+j}$$

We have the result $\| A \| \leq \pi$. I am using the subordinate norm of the Euclidean norm, i.e.,

$$\| A \| = \sup\{\langle Ax,y\rangle:\quad x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n,\quad\Vert x\Vert_2\leq 1,\quad\Vert y\Vert_2\leq 1\}$$

This inequality can be proved using [Hilbert's Inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertsInequality.html). Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205460/norm-of-hilbert-matrix-inequality?rq=1).

**Question:** Do we have an equality? I found nothing on the Internet about such equality.

Comment: You can take a look at this paper : Trick and Treats with the Hilbert matrix http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~jborwein/Expbook/Updates/Already%20Included/choi.pdf


An another way to prove the result is to use Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly not (if you're talking about a finite matrix, rather than an operator on $\ell^2$).  $\pi$ is transcendental, and the norm of a finite matrix with rational entries is an algebraic number.

Comment: I think the OP means either the norm of the infinite-dimensional Hilbert matrix or supremum of all the finite-dimensional norms.

Comment: Note that the OP mentioned ${\mathbb R}^n$, but said nothing about $n \to \infty$.  Still, you may be right.

Comment: Do you have any reference about your result please?

Comment: The one about the norm being an algebraic number?  The norm is obtained by solving an optimization problem.  Just verify that the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions for this problem are equations and inequalities involving algebraic functions, so the solution comes from solving a system of algebraic equations.

Comment: Alternatively, $\|A\|$ is the largest singular value of $A$, which is equal to the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^\ast A$. Since the characteristic polynomial of $A^\ast A$ has rational coefficients, it follows that $\|A\|$ is an algebraic number.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this paper](http://org.uib.no/hcaa/2007hilbert-matrix.pdf), the answer is yes. I'm not familiar with the theorem of Nehari mentioned there; if you assume that, though, you can check that the value of $g(n)$ does produce the Hilbert matrix as indicated and has $L^\infty$ norm $\pi$. (Here $\hat g$ is the Fourier transform of $g$). (The paper refers to the infinite-dimensional Hilbert matrix as an operator $A : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$, but it's not hard to show that a positive result in that case shows that $\pi$ is also the supremum of the corresponding Hilbert matrices $A_n : {\mathbb{R}}^n \to {\mathbb{R}}^n$, if you're dealing with the finite-dimensional case.)

Of course, if you're asking whether any particular $A: {\mathbb{R}}^n \to {\mathbb{R}}^n$ has norm exactly $\pi$, the answer is no; see the comment above.