# Conditional Number growth of Hilbert Matrix: Theoretical vs MatLab.

Tags: matrices, matlab, hilbert-matrices

I need to investigate how the condition number of the Hilbert matrix grows with the size N. The Matlab command is: "cond(hilb(N),2)"

1. Compute the condition number of the Hilbert matrices Hn ∈ R, N×N, for all N = 1, . . . , 50.
2. Using Matlab to calculate the log of condition number of Hn versus N. (The blue 'x')
3. Compare this with the anticipated theoretical growth (The red line) of $$O\left(\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{4N}}{\sqrt{N}}\right) $$

I got a plot like this:

[image]

When N = 13, the Condition Number reaches the maximum. The Condition Number does not continue to grow when N>13. **Why does the Condition Number stop growing after N=13?**

```
% generate Hilbert matrices and compute cond number with 2-norm

N=50; % maximum size of a matrix
condofH = []; % conditional number of Hilbert Matrix
N_it= zeros(1,N); 


% compute the cond number of Hn
for n = 1:N
    Hn = hilb(n);
    N_it(n)=n;
    condofH = [condofH cond(Hn,2)];
end

% at this point we have a vector condofH that contains the condition
% number of the Hilber matrices from 1x1 to 50x50.
% plot on the same graph the theoretical growth line. 


% Theoretical growth of condofH
x = 1:50;
y = (1+sqrt(2)).^(4*x)./(sqrt(x));

% plot
plot(N_it, log(y));
plot(N_it, log(condofH),'x', N_it,log(y));


% plot labels
plot(N_it, log(condofH),'x', N_it,log(y))
title('Conditional Number growth of Hilbert Matrix: Theoretical vs Matlab')
xlabel('N', 'fontsize', 16)
ylabel('log(cond(Hn))','fontsize', 16)
lgd = legend ('Location', 'northwest')
legend('MatLab', 'Theoretical')
legend('show')
```

Comment: Well, the log is in the range of $40$, I.e. the number is in the range of $10^40$ (adsinformation that $\log$ uses base $10$). What is the maximum number that can be represented by floating points? I am not sure that this is the reason, but it could be one factor. Wiki says "the maximum representable IEEE 754 32-bit base-2 floating-point value is (2 − 2−23) × 2127 ≈ 3.402823 × 10^38".

Comment: $e^{40} \approx 2^{57.71}$, as @PhoemueX says it could be numerical issues that occur for large numbers. Exercise does not happen to be part of a course on numerical methods or technical calculations?

Comment: That is still smaller than realmax =  1.7977e+308. Could it be the accumulation of round-off error? I need to reason this phenomena

Comment: $(f/x)^{-1}\cdot \Delta f/\Delta x$, or maximum singular value divided by minimum singular value, or $||A^{-1}||\cdot ||A||$ you could try these alternatives for condition number? (Took from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number)

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=14x14+Hilbert+matrix

Comment: You could also debug in Matlab? Isn't the source code for cond included in  the application?

Comment: The [IEEE machine epsilon](http://courses.math.tufts.edu/math228/Homeworks/Homework2/FloatingPointNumbers_Cleve.pdf) is eps=$2^{-52}$. Calculations in the range above $2^{50}$ has too large round-off errors, which is clearly observed in this MATLAB example.

Comment: @A.Γ. is right, that's what I meant with the 57.7 exponent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to understand what exactly happens here, one has to take a close look at how the command **cond** is implemented in details, which I have not done (see the update at the end). However, one possible explanation for the phenomenon is the following: suppose you have to calculate the function $g(x)=x$, and the calculation is implemented as $g(x)=1/f(x)$ where $f(x)=1/x$. The function $g(x)$ has the linear growth (theoretically), but with floating point calculations for large $x$ (when $1/x$ becomes smaller than the MATLAB [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) eps=$2^{-52}$) you will get round-off errors dominating in the denominator
$$
g(x)\approx\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+{\rm eps}}\approx \frac{1}{{\rm eps}}\approx 2^{52}.
$$
I guess that something similar happens in the command **cond**.

**Update:** After having a look at cond.m I confirm the phenomenon. MATLAB calculates the condition number for $p=2$ via SVD, that is, for Hilbert matrices it becomes
$$
k(H_n)=\frac{\lambda_\max(H_n)}{\lambda_\min(H_n)}.
$$
When $n\to\infty$ we have $\lambda_\max\to\pi$ (e.g. see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837832/norm-of-hilbert-matrix-is-it-equal-to-pi)) and $\lambda_\min\to 0$. Calculation with floating points for large $n$ looks as
$$
k(H_n)\approx\frac{\pi}{\lambda_\min+{\rm eps}}\approx\frac{\pi}{\rm eps}\approx 2^{52}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

MatLab calculates Condition Number in [this way](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cond.html):

$$Cond(H_n) = ||H_n^{−1}||⋅||H_n|| $$

One explanation for this is that MatLab uses: [invhilb(n)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/invhilb.html) to generate Hn-1. According to the MatLab documentation, invhilb(n) gives exact inverse of the Hilbert matrix without roundoff error when N<15. For N>=15, invhilb(n) involves round-off errors and Cond(Hn) Algorithm starts to loose robustness. This explains why Log(cond(Hn)) does not continue to grow after N=14.

For N>=15, I predict MatLab generates Hn-1 using [inv(Hn)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html) The documentation indicates that inv() performs an LU decomposition of Hn. Therefore this algorithm does round-off in $O(2/3N^3)$ times. It suffers from accumulation of roundoff errors.

Comment: Do you have a reference showing that this is the way the condition number is implemented in Matlab?

Comment: cond(X) = norm(X,p) * norm(invhilb(n),p) from documentation of cond()

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cond.html

Comment: Note that what you write is the *definition* on a condition number. According to your link to **cond** it says: *The algorithm for cond (when $p = 2$) uses the singular value decomposition, svd.*  It means that the condition number for the Hilbert matrix is calculated as $$k(H)=\frac{\lambda_\max(H)}{\lambda_\min(H)}.$$ What happens here is *exactly* what I wrote in my answer.